# Have a list of dicts need to write csv file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I need to ouput a list of dicts in python to a csv file.  But I wanted to split them by filename.  I have a list of dicts that looks like this:

```
{'Filename': 'F:\\Desktop\\Metadata\informationtechnologies1.pdf',
  'DESCRIPTION': [u'This is a test sentence.'],
  'NAME': [u'This is a test name'],
  'PERIOD': [],
  'INFO2': [u'TEST1',
   u'TEST2',
   u'TEST3',
   u'TEST4',
   u'TEST5',],
  'INFO': [u'TEST6',
   u'TEST7',
   u'TEST8',
   u'TEST9',
   u'TEST10',
   u'TEST11',]},
 {'Filename': 'F:\\Desktop\informationtechnologies.pdf',
```

I need to print these exactly how it appears in a single column, with the results being in a new row. Preferably a new line after each filename to separate all the results. For example:

`Filename: informationtechnologies1.pdf
DESCRIPTION:
This is a sentence
INFO2:
TEST2
TEST3
TEST4
TEST5`

`Filename:informationtechnologies.pdf`

I have tried the following code but it places it each list into single columns(one column can have a list of 20 pieces of data in the info columns):

```
df = DataFrame.from_dict(results)
df.to_csv("F:\Desktop/meta.csv",encoding='utf-8')
```

I need the data to be all iterated in column 1, so if there is a list within a dict I want each item in that list to print on a new line

Comment: What have you tried so far?  The output format is rather unclear to me, but it doesn't look like CSV.  I also don't understand what you mean by "I wanted to split them by filename".  Please clarify what exactly you want to achieve, and what exactly is causing difficulties for you.

Comment: What determines the order they should be written?  Keeping in mind that `dict`s are unsorted.

Comment: sometimes you are printing the keys and the values in-line `'Filename: informationtechnologies1.pdf'`,in separate lines `'DESCRIPTION: 'This is a test sentence.'`, sometimes none of the two `'NAME: This is a test name'`.

Comment: I guess my question is how do I get both the KEY and VALUES to print on the same column with each iteration on a new line below it

Comment: try df = DataFrame.from_dict(results,orient='index')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you show is not a csv file but a plain text file.

Assuming your requirements are:

- if a directory contains the key `Filename` print on first line the key, a colon, a space and the value
- for all other key, value items in the directory, first print a line with the key followed by a colon, then assuming the value is a list of unicode strings, print each value of the list encoded as utf8 on a line; if the value is not a list, convert it to unicode and print it encoded as utf8
- print an empty line after each directory

I would use explicit loops and tests, because I do not know any tool that does this out of the box:

```
with open("F:\\Desktop/meta.csv", "w") as fd:
    for d in results:
            if 'Filename' in d:
                dummy = fd.write('Filename: ' + d['Filename'] + '\n')
            for k, l in d.iteritems():
                if k != 'Filename':
                    dummy = fd.write(k + ':\n')
                    if isinstance(l, list):
                        for item in l:
                            dummy = fd.write(item.encode('utf8') + '\n')
                    else:
                        dummy = fd.write(unicode(l).encode('utf8') + '\n')
            dummy = fd.write('\n')
```